# Make these specific [jquery-*] and [jquery-ui-*] tags synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The following tags all refer the same jQuery UI components but use both the `jquery-ui-*` prefix and the `jquery-*` prefix. I suggest all of the following tags are made synonyms.

- [jquery-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-dialog) -> [jquery-ui-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-dialog)
- [jquery-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-autocomplete) -> [jquery-ui-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-autocomplete)
- [jquery-droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-droppable) -> [jquery-ui-droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-droppable)
- [jquery-draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-draggable) -> [jquery-ui-draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-draggable)
- [jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) -> [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable)
- [jquery-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-slider) -> [jquery-ui-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-slider)
- [jquery-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-tabs) -> [jquery-ui-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-tabs)
- [jquery-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-tooltip) -> [jquery-ui-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-tooltip)
- [jquery-accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-accordion) -> [jquery-ui-accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-accordion)
- [jquery-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-resizable) -> [jquery-ui-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-resizable)
- [jquery-spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-spinner) -> [jquery-ui-spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-spinner)
- [jquery-multiselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-multiselect) -> [jquery-ui-multiselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-multiselect)
- [jquery-widget-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-widget-factory) -> [jquery-ui-widget-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-widget-factory)

Also:

The tag [jquery-ui-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-menu) could be created to match the existing format and these tags could be synonyms:

- [jqueryui-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqueryui-menu), [jquery-ui-menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-menubar) -> [jquery-ui-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-menu)

Synonyms which already exist:

- [jquery-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datepicker) -> [jquery-ui-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-datepicker)

See also:

- [Synonym request [jquery-autocomplete] -> [jquery-ui-autocomplete]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171276/synonym-request-jquery-autocomplete-jquery-ui-autocomplete)
- [Synonym request [jquery-dialog] -> [jquery-ui-dialog]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171277/synonym-request-jquery-dialog-jquery-ui-dialog)

Comment: [status-completed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327296/2333214)

Comment: All were done except multiselect. Now all are done.