# Help clean up jquery-ui-* tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

This is a follow up to [Should the tags [sortable], [jquery-sortable] and [jquery-ui-sortable] be merged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272146/2333214) <sup>**1**</sup>

I need help of moderators and members with the voting power to clean this up. 
**If you have the privilege please take necessary action**.

|__________ Tag __________| __________ _Synonym(s)____________]

- <del>[jquery-ui-widget-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-widget-factory) - [jquery-widget-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-widget-factory)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-widget-factory/synonyms).

---

- <del>[jquery-ui-draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-draggable) - [jquery-draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-draggable)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-draggable/synonyms)
- <del>[jquery-ui-droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-droppable) - [jquery-droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-droppable)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-droppable/synonyms).
- <del>[jquery-ui-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-resizable) - [jquery-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-resizable)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-resizable/synonyms)
- <del>[jquery-ui-selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-selectable) - [selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectable)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-selectable/synonyms).
- <del>[jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) - [sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable),[jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable)</del> [Synonyms created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-sortable/synonyms).

---

- <del>[jquery-ui-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-autocomplete) - [jquery-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-autocomplete)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-autocomplete/synonyms).
- <del>[jquery-ui-accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-accordion) - [jquery-accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-accordion)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-accordion/synonyms).
- <del>[jquery-ui-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-datepicker) - [jquery-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datepicker)</del>  Synonym exists (Thank heavens).
- <del>[jquery-ui-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-dialog) - [jquery-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-dialog)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-dialog/synonyms)
- <del>[jquery-ui-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-menu) - [jquery-ui-menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-menubar)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-menu/synonyms).
- <del>[jquery-ui-selectmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-selectmenu) - [select-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-menu)</del> [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-selectmenu/synonyms).
- <del>[jquery-ui-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-slider) - [jquery-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-slider)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-slider/synonyms)
- <del>[jquery-ui-spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-spinner) - [jquery-spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-spinner)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-spinner/synonyms)
- <del>[jquery-ui-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-tabs) - [jquery-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-tabs)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-tabs/synonyms)
- <del>[jquery-ui-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-tooltip) - [jquery-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-tooltip)</del>  [Synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-tooltip/synonyms)

Also in case if I missed any widget/synonym please add them to the list.

If you were able to suggest a synonym let us know so that we can vote on it.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> [sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable) and [jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) have been marked as synonyms of [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable).

There are not many people following jQuery UI so I had to directly contact the top users of [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) to successfully create the synonym.

In the process I realized that there is a synonym for all most all jQuery UI widgets. It's not feasible to directly contact active members with the voting power for all these tags. So I'm posting it here.

---

<sup>**2**</sup> I do not have enough votes on the particular widget's tag to suggest synonym

Comment: Nice! Sure... `:)`

Comment: `selectable` doesn't appear to be completely jquery-ui related...

Comment: @JonClements [Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectable/info) says *"Selectable is a jQuery UI plugin that allows for elements to be selected by dragging a box (sometimes called a lasso) with the mouse or clicking."* ..?

Comment: @TJ indeed... but just a quick flick through those and it's also "incorrectly" being used for other things... those could probably do with a re-tag before a syn. is made...

Comment: @JonClements Yes correct, not that many question so re-tag isn't  a problem.

Comment: @JonClements I went though all 170 questions... remaining 152 is actually using jquery-ui-selectable widget...

Comment: Notice on clicking  `sortable ` above the merge to jquery-ui also include a post like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825434/how-to-use-a-library-such-as-sortablejs-in-an-angular-2-0-app which is asking about using a library `sortable.js` in angular app.

Comment: @charlietfl that's just incorrect use of tagging... Like tagging `java` in a `javascript` question... `sortable` tag wiki clearly refers to jQuery UI sortable. The synonym is to actually fix this problem, now that if someone adds `sortable` in their question it'll automatically turn into `jquery-ui-sortable` so that it's easy to realize their mistake.

Comment: I only brought it up since need for using jQuery-ui is dwindling and other libraries/concepts evolve which could make the tag take on new meaning. Is such a generic term though ... could be applied to arrays in any language even.

Comment: @charlietfl Well as of now it's highly misused in place of `jquery-ui-sortable` so it's not possible to effectively follow most of `jquery-ui-*` tags... If new technologies comes up with similar functionalities they need to be tagged with a more specific term since it's such a generic term as you already mentioned (which I completely agree with  hence voting for specific `jquery-ui-` tags). For example the sortable library you mentioned should be tagged `rubaxa-sortable`

Comment: Makes sense to me. Such generic tags seem useless to me anyway but I never search by tag if I need help either

Comment: I added a "`jquery-dialog` should be `jquery-ui-dialog`" suggestion.

Comment: Added suggestion for `jquery-ui-resizable`

Comment: I see you seeking help from mods and very-high-rep users. Why not use jQuery instead?

Comment: @dorukayhan As a matter of fact we are dealing with jQuery ;) BTW it's not very-high-rep users anyone ever got 5 up votes on these jQuery UI widgets can help...

Comment: just use jQuery. `$('[tags]').upvote()` `( •_•)O*¯``·.¸.·´¯°Q(•_• )`

Comment: @JonClements I tried creating `jquery-ui-menu` as suggested in the [well received 2 year old dupe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251115/2333214) and got [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IVtTn.png). Does it have to be another meta post on it's own?

Comment: @TJ I've renamed `jqueryui-menu` to `jquery-ui-menu`...